# How to add a sensor to an object using the BGE Python scripting

Tags: python, game-engine

I want to add a sensor to each of several "players" using the bge + python.  Each sensor will need to have its own distance function, because each player has a different range of perception. This is how I add the players to the scene:

```
for i in range(world_config.initial_population_size):
    pos = Vector((random.uniform(-10,10),
                 random.uniform(-10,10),
                 3))
    p = Player()
    t = own.scene.addObject("Player")        
    t["Player"] = p
    t.worldPosition = pos
```

Now I would like to do something like.

```
t.addSensor(Distance=t["Player"].perception())
```

So that later I can compare which player sees the other in an interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no function `addSensor` in the [API search_1](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_GameObject.html?highlight=add%20sensor)  [API search_2](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.logic.html?highlight=add%20sensor).

So you can't add a sensor through python. The sensor requires to be added in logic editor for a single object, but you can add an object with a sensor and controller to the current scene.

Comment: Thanks. Do you have advice on how to alter the sensor's "Distance" per object?  E.g., so every Player can have their own distance?

Comment: With ``currentController.sensors['sensor_name'].distance = value``, [KX_NearSensor](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_NearSensor.html?highlight=distance#bge.types.KX_NearSensor.distance) [KX_RadarSensor](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bge.types.KX_RadarSensor.html?highlight=distance#bge.types.KX_RadarSensor.distance)